# How to parse multiple parameters to a stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use props and some Redux's actions and state in a stateless component. When I parse props as the first argument, it works but `{additem, removeitem, basket}` doesn't, and vice-versa.

State less component example:

```
const ProductLayout = ({additem, removeitem, basket}, props)=> { 
//Here, additem and removeitem are functions, basket is an array. 

  ...
return (
...)
}
```

Is there any way to parse these arguments in a stateless component or should I use a stateful component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your props are one object. When you pass props directly to the component and also with Redux using `connect`, the two objects (the props you passed directly, and the props from Redux) are merged into the same object.

See this for example:

```
const Thing = ({ foo, bar }) =>
  <span id="foo">{bar}</span>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ foo: state.foo })
const ConnectedThing = connect(mapStateToProps)(Thing)

const SecondThing = () => <Thing bar="bar" />
```

And just a comment, functional components don't have a render method — you can just return the JSX directly.

So in your case, if you want to have `addItem, removeitem`, and `basket` as separate variables and the rest of `props` in an object, what you want is:

```
const ProductLayout = ({additem, removeitem, basket,...props }) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

pass just one, don't use destructuring

```
    const ProductLayout = (props)=> { 
    //Here, additem and removeitem are functions, basket is an array. 
        let {additem, removeitem, basket, myNewVar} = props; // and anything else u need 
      ...
    render (
    ...)
    }
```